# jsgauge - setValue gives Illegal invocation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jsgauge](http://code.google.com/p/jsgauge/) initialised with:

```
$('#gauge').gauge('init');
```

If I try to call

```
$('#gauge').gauge('setValue', 50);
```

With Chrome I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

But it works on Firefox & IE9.
Do you have an idea of why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

This occurs in Google Chrome 12.0.742.100 due to line 49 of jquery.qtip.js, which reads:

```
if(console){
    (console.warn || console.log)(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}
```

Altering the middle line to read `console.warn(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));` works in chrome as expected.

It worked to the guy [here](https://github.com/Craga89/qTip2/issues/183)

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](http://code.google.com/p/jsgauge/issues/detail?id=18) fixed my problem.

Patch gauge.js

```
line 350 & 356
- if (that.cancelRequestAnimFrame) {
+ if (that.cancelRequestAnimFrame && that.cancelRequestAnimFrame.arguments != null) {
```

Comment: So why won't you accept your answer and not mine? =) thx any way.